# Move movieclips to unique layers using JSFL

Tags: flash, workflow, jsfl

I have an asset file (FLA) that will be updated a lot by other team members during the project. I would like to have an JSFL script that moves all selected movieclips in the timeline to a new layer (named using the movieclips library name).

- Layer 0

  - instance88 (test1)
  - instance89 (test2)

... will become ...

- test1

  - instance88
- test2

  - instance89

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you name the test1 and test2 instances, you can right click them and select **Distribute To Layers** from the context menu, which should place the movieclips on separate layers, named after their instance names.

You could write a jsfl script, but you're requirements look a bit loose. The symbols names might change, could be more than 2 symbols with this behaviour, etc. 
At this point it might be more than trouble than it's worth.

Personally, I would use designer assets as **named instances** in a MovieClip with the **Export for Actionscript** option ticked all compiled into a single **SWC**. This way, you can simply **access the assets** by instance names from the linked SWC and use them via **composition** (or **inheritance**, depending on what's best suited for you) in your actionscript projects.

HTH